# Word application crashes after close and reopen

Tags: sharepoint, interop

I have a situation where, whenever a new new document is saved (New Document > Save As) in the Sharepoint library, a custom event handler (ItemAdded) fires an update on the document record and populate some column values. Also the document is check-in programatically. These changes remain invisible from the word interface since it triggers in the back end. I need to close and reopen the document from the server so that it opens with all Server Properties and correct Checked-out status. I am using the following code to close and open:

```
    Word._Document doc = this.Application.ActiveDocument;
    doc.Close(Word.WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges, System.Type.Missing, System.Type.Missing);
    Word.Document aDoc = this.Application.Documents.Open(docPath, System.Type.Missing, true, System.Type.Missing, System.Type.Missing, System.Type.Missing, System.Type.Missing, System.Type.Missing, System.Type.Missing, System.Type.Missing, System.Type.Missing, true, System.Type.Missing, System.Type.Missing, System.Type.Missing, System.Type.Missing);
    aDoc.Activate();
```

The document closes fine but the application crashes on open. However, if I only close the document from code and open the document from recent files list manually, the documents open fine. Is there some clean-up I need to do before I can open the document?

Please note that, I have overriden the default save operation of word using DocumentBeforeSave event (Cancel=true). Not sure if thats relevant information or not.

EDIT: I tried to catch if the above block thows any COMException or any kind of exception at all, but it does not. It simply crashes on the open statement.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the following:

```
        (new Thread(() =>
        {
            doc.Close(Word.WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges, System.Type.Missing, System.Type.Missing);

        })).Start();
```